# Recommendation for tree structured note-taking software

Tags: windows, android, open-source, text-editor, spreadsheet

Good morning, I'm looking for a note software that does this:

1. Organization of notes in the form of a tree with nesting without limitation.
2. Tables can be created and customized.
3. Customization of notes (you can change their icon, style)
4. Text editor containing options like numbered list, change font, highlight color, paste images and other controls like bold, etc.
5. It is important that there is how to create a spreadsheet note.
6. Cross-platform that works on android

I have already found a software like this, it is called [Rightnote](https://www.bauerapps.com/rightnote/), but it is very expensive in pro version and I would prefer something cheap or free if possible.

I have tried:

Notion, myBase Desktop, all my notes organizer, mempad, tree notes, EssentialPIM Pro, WinOrganizer and myInfo but they do not meet the requirements.

I appreciate your contributions